# Can't create svg circles in groups

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to create three groups of circles in an SVG. I called them `circleA` `circleB` and `circleC` and I am intending to color them differently.

```
var circleA = [
    [50,48],[106,35],[107,42],[119,52],[139,58],
    [26,60],[65,68],[117,73],[123,70],[145,78]
];

var circleB = [
    [38,81],[48,69],[48,81],
    [111,99],[128,92],[153,92]
];

var circleC = [
    [24,106],[46,99],[43,112],[63,105],
    [62,122],[92,126],[141,122],[132,145],
    [23,145]
];

//... omitting code for scale handling ... 

var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgw)
        .attr("height", svgh);


    svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(circleA)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
   .attr("r", 10);

   svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(circleB)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
   .attr("r", 10);

   svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(circleC)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
   .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
   .attr("r", 10);
```

However only `circleA` were added to the SVG. Group B and C are not there. I checked the DOM indeed there were only 10 `<circle>` tags created instead of 10 + 6 + 9 = 25 circles created.

Why is that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(circleB)
```

will select all the existing `circle` elements and bind the data `circleB` to them. You already created 10 `circle` after binding `circleA`, so now `circleB` is bound to the first 6 existing `circle` elements. Since no *new* elements have to be created (the existing ones are "reused"), the `.enter()` selection is empty and nothing happens.

So, the overall problem is that you are trying to bind different data to the same elements. If you want to create elements for each of the data sets, you have to modify your selector. For example, you could give the elements belonging to different data sets a different class:

```
svg.selectAll("circle.a")
.data(circleA)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'a')
//...

svg.selectAll("circle.b")
.data(circleB)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr('class', 'b')
//...
```

Comment: Thanks it is working now. However is this considered a normal practice or is it more like a quick workaround that forces it to create additional circles using CSS selector? Is there a so-called "proper" way or an alternative?

Comment: It depends on the data. Using data joins how Lars suggested is another approach. However, since you already said that you have three distinct groups, I don't see why using a class to "mark" each of the groups is bad.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way D3 matches data to elements. By default, the matching is done by index. That is, in your subsequent `.data(...).selectAll(...)` calls, you're selecting the existing circles and matching them to the data by index. As there are more circles than data items, the `.enter()` selection is empty.

The solution to this is to provide a matching function through the optional second argument of `.data()`, e.g. something like `.data(..., function(d) { return d; })`.

Comment: I understand the cause now but I don't really understand the said solution. I just went to read the api and still cannot seem to understand how the addition of the function make things work. If you would be so kind to help me understand this?

Comment: The function tells D3 how to match data to existing elements. By supplying the function I've suggested, you're telling to inspect the actual data. That is, only if there is already a circe that was generated by the exact same data, it will be matched. It exploits the fact that your data are unique across the arrays, while the array indices (the default behaviour) aren't.